# LongPoll: Stop Firefox-Throbber

Tags: ajax, dojo, long-polling, throbber

I use [dojo/request/xhr](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/xhr.html) for longpoll requests. In Firefox (not in IE or Crome) the throbber spins during the request.

From technical view this is correct, because a request has not finished yet. But this looks not very nice. Is there a way to stop it?

There are some posts about "Throbber of doom", but I can't find a solution. Is there any?

Frank.

P.S. Maybe it could be possible to emit an event to feign a completed request, that will make the throbber stop!?

P.P.S. Is it a known bug? See here: [Mozilla throbber bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=463210)
But it seems not to be processed!?

**New trials**:
Using a basic [JavaScript XMLHttpRequest Object](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) the throbber doesn't spin! Seems to be a problem with Dojo-Xhr!?